# Find out wheter <?xml-stylesheet ?> node exists in xml-document

Tags: java, ant, xmltask

I've got a XML-document with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/Stylesheet.xsl" ?>
```

How can I find out using ANT's `<xmltask>` whether the `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` node already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a special node type called **processing instruction**. 
You can query it using **XPath** to find out if it exists and what its attributes are:

```
/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')
```

Comment: That works flawlessly. How can I get the type or href-attribute?

Comment: That's tricky, because processing instructions have pseudo-attributes, which cannot be directly accessed. You can however extract the content as string, and use the XPATH sting functions to get the href value:
substring-before(substring-after( string(/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')),'href="'), '"')